# spectate data from core data

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

Is there any way that I can spectate my data in database which is in my database created whit core data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database is in SQLite format and you if you are using the simulator you can access it in `~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/[current version]/Applications/[some guid]`

`[current version]` will be like 4.2 and `[some guid]` will be a guid identifier and you can just open up each folder and look for your application. Inside of one of the subdirectories of your application you should find a SQLite database. That file can be opened with tools such as [Lita](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/marketplace/index.cfm?event=marketplace.offering&offeringid=10386&marketplaceid=1) and a [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) plugin for Firefox.